# How do I move an image to the left?

Tags: html, css

I am very new to coding still and I'm testing out a website I made. I need some help on a way to move images where I want. As you can see the gif is out of place with the caption, I need the image to be directly centered under the caption. Here is the code. Beware some of the code is copy pasted for example the galaxy background.

```css
body {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at bottom, navy 0, black 100%);
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.space {
  background: rgba(128, 0, 128, 0.1) center / 200px 200px round;
  border: 1px dashed purple;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.stars1 {
  animation: space 180s ease-in-out infinite;
  background-image: radial-gradient(1px 1px at 25px 5px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), radial-gradient(1px 1px at 50px 25px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), radial-gradient(1px 1px at 125px 20px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), radial-gradient(1.5px 1.5px at 50px 75px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), radial-gradient(2px 2px at 15px 125px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), radial-gradient(2.5px 2.5px at 110px 80px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
}

.stars2 {
  animation: space 240s ease-in-out infinite;
  background-image: radial-gradient(1px 1px at 75px 125px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), radial-gradient(1px 1px at 100px 75px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), radial-gradient(1.5px 1.5px at 199px 100px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), radial-gradient(2px 2px at 20px 50px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), radial-gradient(2.5px 2.5px at 100px 5px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), radial-gradient(2.5px 2.5px at 5px 5px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
}

.stars3 {
  animation: space 300s ease-in-out infinite;
  background-image: radial-gradient(1px 1px at 10px 10px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), radial-gradient(1px 1px at 150px 150px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), radial-gradient(1.5px 1.5px at 60px 170px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), radial-gradient(1.5px 1.5px at 175px 180px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), radial-gradient(2px 2px at 195px 95px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), radial-gradient(2.5px 2.5px at 95px 145px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
}

.earth_figure {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

@keyframes space {
  40% {
    opacity: 0.75;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.25;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 0.75;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Orbitron&display=swap');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Space</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Space 2.css">
    <style>
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Orbitron&display=swap');
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="space stars1"></div>
    <div class="space stars2"></div>
    <div class="space stars3"></div>
    <h1 style= "color:white;text-align:center;font-family:Orbitron;font-size:300%;">Space</h1>
    <figure class="earth_figure">
      <img src="Earth Spinning.gif" height="329" width="329" alt="Earth">
      <figcaption style="color:white;font-family:Orbitron;font-size:300%">Earth</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <h2 style= "font-family:Arial;color:white;">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you trying to have earth and the gif centered under space?

Comment: Try adding `align-items: center;` property to the `.earth_figure` class

Comment: @JonathanAkweteyOkine No, I am trying to have the word "Earth" be centred above the gif. "Space" is the heading of the page and must stay centred at the top above everything else.

Comment: @TariqulIslam Can you explain it means?

Comment: @Enzie As far I can guess, you want to center align the title "Earth", so using `align-items: center;` on the parent (in your case `<figure>`) will make the child items (in your case `<img>` and `<figcaption>`) to align center.

Comment: @TariqulIslam Sorry, If i'm explaining this wrong, basically my vision for the site, is to have a "showcase" of the different planets, each having their own name on the top and placing the planets in line from the left to the right starting with Earth, The code you said makes the Space title and the Earth heading all in the middle.

Comment: @TariqulIslam Like this https://www.universetoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Stamps_planets.jpg

Comment: @Enzie Check my answer below if you want something like this.

Comment: @TariqulIslam That is a lot of new code, If you could explain it to me so I don't just copy paste it and not learn anything

Comment: @Enzie If you look closely you will see it's just all repeated code. I encourage you to explore it yourself, I believe you will understand most of the changes by yourself. I will explain any specific point that you couldn't understand.

Comment: @TariqulIslam I see you typed all in the <div> tag, what does that do?

Comment: And what was the code you put in the css? I don't have much knowledge for css.

Comment: @Enzie I put all the `<figure>` tags inside a parent `div` which has an id `#planer-wrapper`. This is the parent div that contains all the planets(`<figure>`) and if your look at the css of `#planet-wrapper` id, you will see it displays all the planets side by side.

Comment: What I wrote in css is very basic css code. As you are working with HTML and CSS, you should follow some tutorials on that topics.

Comment: @TariqulIslam Okay I will mark your code as the answer, but I'm gonna try and rewrite it myself to understand it better.Thank you.

Comment: There are plenty of resources out there. Just search and explore, specially css `flexbox`. This is what I used here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out...

```css
  body {
      background: radial-gradient(circle at bottom, navy 0, black 100%);
      height: 100vh;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .space {
      background: rgba(128, 0, 128, 0.1) center / 200px 200px round;
      border: 1px dashed purple;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
    }
    
    .stars1 {
      animation: space 180s ease-in-out infinite;
      background-image: 
        radial-gradient(1px 1px at 25px 5px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), 
        radial-gradient(1px 1px at 50px 25px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), 
        radial-gradient(1px 1px at 125px 20px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), 
        radial-gradient(1.5px 1.5px at 50px 75px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), 
        radial-gradient(2px 2px at 15px 125px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), 
        radial-gradient(2.5px 2.5px at 110px 80px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
    }
    
    .stars2 {
      animation: space 240s ease-in-out infinite;
      background-image: 
        radial-gradient(1px 1px at 75px 125px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), 
        radial-gradient(1px 1px at 100px 75px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), 
        radial-gradient(1.5px 1.5px at 199px 100px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), 
        radial-gradient(2px 2px at 20px 50px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), 
        radial-gradient(2.5px 2.5px at 100px 5px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), 
        radial-gradient(2.5px 2.5px at 5px 5px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
    }
    
    .stars3 {
      animation: space 300s ease-in-out infinite;
      background-image: 
        radial-gradient(1px 1px at 10px 10px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), 
        radial-gradient(1px 1px at 150px 150px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), 
        radial-gradient(1.5px 1.5px at 60px 170px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), 
        radial-gradient(1.5px 1.5px at 175px 180px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), 
        radial-gradient(2px 2px at 195px 95px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), 
        radial-gradient(2.5px 2.5px at 95px 145px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
    }
    
    .earth_figure {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
        align-items: center;
    }
    #planet-wrapper{
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     justify-content: space-around;
    }
    
    @keyframes space {
      40% {
        opacity: 0.75;
      }
      50% {
        opacity: 0.25;
      }
      60% {
        opacity: 0.75;
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Orbitron&display=swap');
```

```html
 <div class="space stars1"></div>
 <div class="space stars2"></div>
 <div class="space stars3"></div>
 <h1 style= "color:white;text-align:center;font-family:Orbitron;font-size:300%;">Space</h1>
  <div id="planet-wrapper">
    <figure class="earth_figure">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fPP7RJO.gif" height="80" width="80" alt="Earth">
      <figcaption style="color:white;font-family:Orbitron;font-size:200%">Earth</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="earth_figure">
       <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fPP7RJO.gif" height="80" width="80" alt="Earth">
       <figcaption style="color:white;font-family:Orbitron;font-size:200%">Mars</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="earth_figure">
     <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fPP7RJO.gif" height="80" width="80" alt="Earth">
     <figcaption style="color:white;font-family:Orbitron;font-size:200%">Jupiter</figcaption>
   </figure>
   <figure class="earth_figure">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fPP7RJO.gif" height="80" width="80" alt="Earth">
      <figcaption style="color:white;font-family:Orbitron;font-size:200%">Saturn</figcaption>
   </figure>
   <figure class="earth_figure">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fPP7RJO.gif" height="80" width="80" alt="Earth">
    <figcaption style="color:white;font-family:Orbitron;font-size:200%">Uranus</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="earth_figure">
     <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fPP7RJO.gif" height="80" width="80" alt="Earth">
     <figcaption style="color:white;font-family:Orbitron;font-size:200%">Neptune</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="earth_figure">
   <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fPP7RJO.gif" height="80" width="80" alt="Earth">
   <figcaption style="color:white;font-family:Orbitron;font-size:200%">Mercury</figcaption>
 </figure>
 <figure class="earth_figure">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fPP7RJO.gif" height="80" width="80" alt="Earth">
    <figcaption style="color:white;font-family:Orbitron;font-size:200%">Venus</figcaption>
 </figure>
  </div>
 <h2 style= "font-family:Arial;color:white;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML structure is not correct, try to see this code

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Orbitron&display=swap');
body {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at bottom, navy 0, black 100%);
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.space {
  background: rgba(128, 0, 128, 0.1) center / 200px 200px round;
  border: 1px dashed purple;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.stars1 {
  animation: space 180s ease-in-out infinite;
  background-image: radial-gradient(1px 1px at 25px 5px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), radial-gradient(1px 1px at 50px 25px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), radial-gradient(1px 1px at 125px 20px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), radial-gradient(1.5px 1.5px at 50px 75px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), radial-gradient(2px 2px at 15px 125px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), radial-gradient(2.5px 2.5px at 110px 80px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
}

.stars2 {
  animation: space 240s ease-in-out infinite;
  background-image: radial-gradient(1px 1px at 75px 125px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), radial-gradient(1px 1px at 100px 75px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), radial-gradient(1.5px 1.5px at 199px 100px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), radial-gradient(2px 2px at 20px 50px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), radial-gradient(2.5px 2.5px at 100px 5px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), radial-gradient(2.5px 2.5px at 5px 5px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
}

.stars3 {
  animation: space 300s ease-in-out infinite;
  background-image: radial-gradient(1px 1px at 10px 10px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), radial-gradient(1px 1px at 150px 150px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), radial-gradient(1.5px 1.5px at 60px 170px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), radial-gradient(1.5px 1.5px at 175px 180px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), radial-gradient(2px 2px at 195px 95px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), radial-gradient(2.5px 2.5px at 95px 145px, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
}

.earth_figure {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.earth_figure h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  text-align: center;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.earth_figure h1:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: 55%;
}

@keyframes space {
  40% {
    opacity: 0.75;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.25;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 0.75;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Space</title>
    <style>
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Orbitron&display=swap');
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Space 2.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="space stars1"></div>
    <div class="space stars2"></div>
    <div class="space stars3"></div>
    <figure class="earth_figure">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/07/23/15/06/mobile-phone-5431597__340.jpg" height="329" width="329" alt="Earth">
      <h1 style= "color:white;text-align:center;font-family:Orbitron;font-size:300%;">Space</h1>
      <h1 style="color:white;font-family:Orbitron;font-size:300%">Earth</h1>
    </figure>
    <h2 style= "font-family:Arial;color:white;"> </h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain why it is incorrect? I am trying to learn.

Comment: you missing the end tag of head tag and h1 tag also don't write any html tag like div, span etc tag inside head tag see more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/The_head_metadata_in_HTML

Comment: The code you put makes both words go inside the gif?

Answer (score 0):

```
.earth_figure {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    text-align: center;
}
    .earth_figure img {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 30%;
}
```

mabe try this
https://jsfiddle.net/m8t5qzy2/

Comment: Can you explain what it does?

Comment: kinda hard to understand what your trying to do i just centered everything and positioned the earth gif in the centre

Comment: Earth Spinning.gif host it on imgur or something pls